# Adding to an object ArrayList from another Class

Tags: java, arraylist, junit4

I have a Class named Item.

```
public class Item {

private int code;
private String name;
private double price;
private int quantity;

public Item(int code, String name, double price, int quantity) {
    setCode(code);
    setName(name);
    setPrice(price);
    setQuantity(quantity);
}
//Item getters and setters
```

And I have a Class named Stock that creates an ArrayList of Items.

```
public class Stock {
private ArrayList<Item> stock;

public Stock() {
    stock = new ArrayList<Item>();
}

public ArrayList<Item> getStock() {
    return stock;
}
```

I also have a Class named ItemRegister that adds an Item to the Stock.

```
public class ItemRegister extends Stock {

public void registerItem(String name, double price) {
    getStock().add(new Item(setItemCode(), name, price, 0));
}

private int setItemCode() {
    return getStock().size() + 1;
}
```

I'm using unit tests to see if I did add an Item to the Stock.

```
public class ItemRegisterTest {

@Test
public void testIfHasRegisteredItemInStock() {
    Stock s = new Stock();
    assertTrue(s.getStock().size() == 0);
    ItemRegister i = new ItemRegister();        
    i.registerItem("Oleo", 20.0);
    assertTrue(s.getStock().size() == 1);
}
```

}

When I run these tests it is returning an error.
On the second `assertTrue`, if I test with the object `i` it'll return true but what I want is to add to `Stock` and not `ItemRegister` because if later on I wanna consult `Stock` I'll call `Stock` and not `ItemRegister`.

Comment: Do you think your `s` object is in any way related to your `i` object? Why or why not?

Comment: Just check i instead of s: `assertTrue(i.getStock().size() == 1);`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not really. Because i'm instantianting a new object

Comment: Change the `s` by `i` like this assertTrue(i.getStock().size() == 1); `s` has zero elements.

Comment: Hi @SergeiSirik Later on I wanna try and make a selling class and I wanna consult from Stock but it is not adding how I wanted it

Comment: If they are different objects, why do you expect `s` size to change?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that's true. How can I consult Stock later then? any tips?

Comment: The way you've set up your class hierarchy, an `ItemRegister` IS-A `Stock`. So just consult the `ItemRegister`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the clarification, you guys really helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want is to add to `Stock` and not `ItemRegister` because if later on I wanna consult `Stock` I'll call Stock and not `ItemRegister`.

Then you need to wrap `Stock` into `ItemRegister`.

```
public class ItemRegister  {
    Stock stock;
    public ItemRegister(Stock stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public void registerItem(String name, double price) {
        stock.getStock().add(new Item(setItemCode(), name, price, 0));
    }

    private int setItemCode() {
        return stock.getStock().size() + 1;
    }
}
```

Use it in your unit tests like this:

```
public class ItemRegisterTest {
    @Test
    public void testIfHasRegisteredItemInStock() {
        Stock s = new Stock();
        assertTrue(s.getStock().size() == 0);
        ItemRegister i = new ItemRegister(s);        
        i.registerItem("Oleo", 20.0);
        assertTrue(s.getStock().size() == 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, what you can do is maybe changing the parent-child relationship and having the ItemRegister holding an instance of a Stock object. So, you can modify the ItemRegister class like this:

```
public class ItemRegister  {
    Stock s;
    public ItemRegister(Stock s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void registerItem(String name, double price) {
        s.getStock().add(new Item(setItemCode(), name, price, 0));
    }

    private int setItemCode() {
        return s.getStock().size() + 1;
    }
}
```

Then, the test code you originally wrote will be true with a slight modification `ItemRegister i = new ItemRegister(s);`, and you can work on one instance of Stock object.